# Ignore 'styles.scss.cache' file for version control in a Vaadin 8.1 project?

Tags: css, caching, version-control, mercurial, vaadin

After doing the first Maven `install` on my new Vaadin 8.1 project created from the `vaadin-archetype-widget` Maven archetype, and first running my app, I noticed a single new file appeared:

> myproject-demo/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/demo/styles.scss.cache

➠ Does it make sense to include or ignore this file from my version control?

By *ignore*, I mean add that filename to my list of file/folders to big ignored by my version control system. (`.hgignore` file)

If I intend to share this project as open-source, should I include this file to save a step during build? Or does it get rebuilt frequently, so it would be annoying with frequent changes and needlessly flag an irrelevant change, so I should ignore it?

---

Using [Mercurial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) for version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore styles.scss.cache. It is generated by the Vaadin servlet after it compiles your style for the first time. Cache entry is controlled by [VaadinServlet on row 1107](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServlet.java#L1107) and it will be good to let the server to create and invalidate this file when necessary.

On the fly compilation of SCSS works fine but if that turns out to be "too slow" you can compile your theme to flat styles.css file with maven. For example, Vaadin is compiling Valo theme into vaadin-themes library and you could do similar artefact from your theme. See [Vaadin theme documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/v8/themes/themes-compiling.html) for more details.